# Writing python tests like Qunitjs

Tags: python, testing, qunit, pytest

I'm trying to find a similar approach to Qunit's assertions in Python. When using assertions in Qunit, the message parameter is used in a very descriptive fashion.

```
test( "test", function() {
  ok( fn([])==None, "Function should return 0 if no users" );
  ok( fn(["Test User"])==1, "Function should return 1 is users supplied" );
});
```

Python's unittest module on the other hand, uses the message parameter is a somewhat more negative context. These are only shown when an assertion fails.

```
class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_choice(self):
        seq = range(10)
        element = random.choice(seq)
        self.assertTrue(element in seq, msg="Element not found in sequence")
```

The end result of the Qunit is that there is much clearer transcript which could be compared against a spec document.

I realise that in Python, a similar approach would be achieved by perhaps say writing

```
def test_choice_ensure_element_exists_in_sequence(self):
```

It's not the same though. The output isn't presented in a nice way, and test lifecycle then performs setup and teardown for each label you want to use, which isn't necessarily what you want.

There might be a library out there which takes this approach, so perhaps this issue is already solved. Neither the python unittest library or pytest appear to work in this fashion though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be simply that don't know the unittest libary well enough yet. I find being able to write

```
self.assertIn('s', (1,3,4))
```

To be very short, expressive and readable.

And if you use the correct assertion method on the testcase then you rarely need to add your own message. `assertIn` has a perfectly reasonable output all by itself:

```
AssertionError: 's' not found in (1, 3, 4)
```

So rather than writing heaps of comments/message code. I rely on well named assertions combined with helpful default messages. If a well named assertion and helpful error message has not already been provided then I extend the test case and add my own.

```
self.assert_user_is_administrator(user)
```

Is very readable and will have a nice message if it fails that I provided in only one location.

Comment: The issue isn't so much how the code looks, it's the output. When I run the quint tests I get a very nice transcript stating what tests have been run and what actions those have performed. The equivalent in python simply gives the tests, not the actions, unless of course they fail.

Comment: Oh, you're one of those people :) Yeah, test output for me is `...` or a call to action.